# Why we reshape images in Keras to 4d for image claissification

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, artificial-intelligence, image-classification

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, array_to_img, img_to_array, load_img

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rotation_range=40,
        width_shift_range=0.2,
        height_shift_range=0.2,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True,
        fill_mode='nearest')

img = load_img('data/train/cats/cat.0.jpg')  # this is a PIL image
x = img_to_array(img)  # this is a Numpy array with shape (3, 150, 150)
x = x.reshape((1,) + x.shape)  # this is a Numpy array with shape (1, 3, 150, 150)
```

I don't know why we reshape and make its shape to (1, 3, 150, 150) as in line `X = x.reshape((1,) + x.shape)`and what 1 means here and what is the benefit of that.
This example is from https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html

Comment: Neural network expect batches of data to calculate the loss for. If you have a multi-channel image (eg. RGB), that the batch dimension will be the 4th dim in count and the first one in the data shape (shape[0]). In your code the batch size is 1, which means one batch will have one image.

Answer (score 1):

While 3 is the number of channels (R, G and B) and 150 is the width/height of your image, 1 is **the size of your batch**.

Usually, machine learning methods like neural networks process multiple images at a time. If you process n images at a time, n is your **batch size** and your tensor will have a shape of (**n**, 3, 150, 150).

Comment: thank you so much i am literally confused why we are reshaping our tensor

Comment: Hi @AkshatSingh if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.